# Is it possible to create an Azure CDN with Azure Files Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn, azure-files

All the documentation talks about Azure **Blob** Storage to be used with CDN. Unfortunately the Azure Web Portal doesn't allow me to upload any "blobs" to the Blob storage. On the other side I can do that with a **Files storage type**.

**However I wasn't able to access my Files storage through my CDN Endpoint. Is it not supported?**

Do I need to use Blob Storage and upload files programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can only access Azure File storage via SMB or Rest API. If you want to use anonymous Http access, I would suggest your choose Azure blob storage. If you want to use CDN in Azure file storage. I think you need to write a web application and access the files via Rest API. Then you only need to connect CDN with your web application.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are saying Azure CDN has no way accessing files on an azure storage "files store" - not even Azure internally. CDN should translate HTTP GET image to the corresponding REST API call ;-)

Comment: Yes, if Blob storage could achieve your requirement. It is very easy to use Azure CDN.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/) or the confusingly-named [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) to upload files to blob storage and thus place yourself in a supported scenario?

[image]

Comment: Great hint. I only knew Cloud Explorer from within Visual Studio. That might be a helpful tool down to the road for department specialists.