# Refresh of cache after changing the content of the file in cdn blob storage ASP.NET

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, blob, cdn

Is there any way how to change cache control in azure storage account with CDN by .NET ?

I have UploadFilesAsync method, whitch upload new file into blob storage and also this method update content of file with same name.

Problem is, when I update content of file, then CDN endpoint returns cached old content.

My idea is, that a I set cache control on 10 second and then cached content refresh with actual content, but it doesn't work.

In the azure portal I see that cache control is setted but but cached contant doesn't refresh

What can I do? Thanks.

My UploadFilesAsync method

```
public async Task<ImageInfoDto> UploadFilesAsync(string fileName, Stream fileStream, string contentType, bool isUpdated)
    {
        try
        {
            var storageAccount =
                CloudStorageAccount
                    .Parse(_configuration["StorageAccountConnectionString"]);

            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            var container =
                blobClient.GetContainerReference(_configuration["BlobStorageContainerName"]);

            var cdnEndpoint = _configuration["CdnEndpoint"];

            var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

            using var ms = new MemoryStream();

            fileStream.Position = 0;
            await fileStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;
            await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(ms);

            if (isUpdated)
            {
                blob.Properties.CacheControl = "s-maxage=10";
            }

            blob.Properties.ContentType = contentType;

            await blob.SetPropertiesAsync();

            return new ImageInfoDto
            {
                StorageUrl = blob.Uri.ToString(),
                CdnUrl = cdnEndpoint + "/" + container.Name + "/" + fileName,
                ContentType = contentType
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed");
        }
    }
```

Comment: AFIk, There is no method in dotnet for caching but we can use Azure CDN caching rules to set or modify default cache expiration behavior both globally and with conditions, such as a URL path and file [extensions](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/cdn/cdn-caching-rules.md). we can also use CDN caching rules to set or modify default cache expiration behavior both globally and with conditions, such as a URL path and file extensions.

Comment: After enabling Azure CDN access to a storage account, all publicly available objects are eligible for CDN POP caching. If you modify an object that's currently cached in the CDN, the new content will not be available via Azure CDN until Azure CDN refreshes its content after the time-to-live period for the cached content [expires](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/cdn/cdn-caching-rules.md). we can set the CacheControl property on the blob to expire in 10 seconds (s-maxage=10).

Answer (score 0):

The CDN not refreshing cached content while  updating a file in Azure Blob Storage is likely due to the CDN's caching settings. Setting the `CacheControl` property on the blob object is correct, but the CDN might have its own caching configuration that is affecting the behavior.

To force the CDN to refresh its cache when you update the content of a file, you can use cache-busting techniques. One common approach is to append a unique query parameter to the URL when requesting the file. This makes the CDN treat the request as a new request and fetch the latest version of the file.

- Create an [Azure CDN](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/azure/static-hosting-with-azure-blob-storage-and-azure-cdn/) with Azure  [Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116491/is-it-possible-to-create-an-azure-cdn-with-azure-files-storage).
- Uploaded files to [blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70259171/upload-files-to-blob-storage-via-azure-front-door) storage via Azure [CND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52864283/how-to-get-azure-cdn-link-for-file-in-azure-blob#:%7E:text=var%20storageAccount%20%3D%20CloudStorageAccount.Parse%20%28configuration.ConnectionString%29%3B%20var%20client%20%3D,cancellationToken%29%3B%20return%20blockBlob.Uri%3B%20%2F%2F%20return%20blob%20blob%20url)
- Used  URL access for Azure   [CDN](https://serverfault.com/questions/789960/azure-file-storage-cdn)   with [SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-sas-storage-support)  .

[image]

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

public class ImageService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ILogger<ImageService> _logger;

    public ImageService(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<ImageService> logger)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<ImageInfoDto> UploadFileAsync(string localFilePath, string fileName, string contentType, bool isUpdated)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get configuration values
            string? storageConnectionString = _configuration["StorageConnectionString"];
            string? blobContainerName = _configuration["BlobContainerName"];
            string? cdnEndpoint = _configuration["CdnEndpoint"];

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(storageConnectionString) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(blobContainerName) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cdnEndpoint))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Configuration values are missing or empty.");
            }

            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainerName);

            var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

            using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath))
            {
                await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
            }

            if (isUpdated)
            {
                // Append a cache-busting query parameter to the URL
                var uniqueQueryParam = $"cb={Guid.NewGuid()}";
                var cdnUrl = $"{cdnEndpoint}/{container.Name}/{fileName}?{uniqueQueryParam}";
                return new ImageInfoDto
                {
                    StorageUrl = blob.Uri.ToString(),
                    CdnUrl = cdnUrl,
                    ContentType = contentType
                };
            }

            blob.Properties.ContentType = contentType;
            await blob.SetPropertiesAsync();

            return new ImageInfoDto
            {
                StorageUrl = blob.Uri.ToString(),
                CdnUrl = $"{cdnEndpoint}/{container.Name}/{fileName}",
                ContentType = contentType
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed");
            throw;
        }
    }

    public class ImageInfoDto
    {
        public string? StorageUrl { get; set; }
        public string? CdnUrl { get; set; }
        public string? ContentType { get; set; }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Configuration values (replace with your actual values)
        string? storageConnectionString = "";
        string? blobContainerName = "";
        string? cdnEndpoint = " ";

        // Create configuration
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddInMemoryCollection(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string?>("StorageConnectionString", storageConnectionString),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string?>("BlobContainerName", blobContainerName),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string?>("CdnEndpoint", cdnEndpoint)
            })
            .Build();

        // Create logger (you can configure it as needed)
        var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddConsole();
        });
        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ImageService>();

        // Create ImageService with the configuration and logger
        var imageService = new ImageService(configuration, logger);

        // Example usage
        string localFilePath = " ";
        string fileName = "sample1.jpg";
        string contentType = "image/jpeg";
        bool isUpdated = false;

        try
        {
            var imageInfo = await imageService.UploadFileAsync(localFilePath, fileName, contentType, isUpdated);
            Console.WriteLine($"Storage URL: {imageInfo.StorageUrl}");
            Console.WriteLine($"CDN URL: {imageInfo.CdnUrl}");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]